# How can there not be purpose movement in the fetus until week 18, when a fetus can open its mouth and suck its fingers at week 11?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, human-physiology, embryology

According to [Fetal Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetal_movement)

> According to an overview produced by the Royal College of Physicians
>   of Edinburgh, purposive movement begins at about 18 weeks, gradually
>   replacing reflex movements

but in the same article says

> At week 11, the fetus can open its mouth and suck its fingers; at week
>   12, it begins to swallow amniotic fluid.

I highly doubt that open a mouth and suck its fingers can be classified as "reflex movements", then how it is asserted that there is not purpose movement in the fetus until week 18 when a fetus can open its mouth and suck its fingers at week 11?

Comment: Why do you doubt that finger-sucking is a reflex?

Comment: Did you ever put a finger in an infant's mouth :) It's about as reflexive as it can be. +1 for a well researched question though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swallowing [(Nishino, 2013)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3539657/) and sucking ([rooting reflex](https://www.urmc.rochester.edu/encyclopedia/content.aspx?ContentTypeID=90&ContentID=P02630)) are reflexes. The fingers may just happen to be in the vicinity of its oral region (they often are; Fig. 1.), and oh boy are babies keen to grab a nipple when it's close! Mouth openings can henceforth be also reflexive, being part of the rooting reflex.

[image: hands on head]
<sup>Fig. 1. Fetal hands in facial area. sourceL: [ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/Health/fetal-faces-hint-moms-stress/story?id=23975786)</sup>

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Nishino, *Front Physiol* (2012); **3**: 4892013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3539657/)</sub>